# CC1 cannot be initialized in the class definition, why? then how will I initialize it? please someone help me

Tags: c++

CC1 cannot be initialized in the class definition, why? then how will I initialize it?

```
 class X
    {
    public:
     X(){}
     const char CC1 = 25;       // Line1
     static const int SCI = 50; // Line2
    } ;

        int main()

    {
     X Obj1;
    }
```

Comment: How will you initialize it? `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 1):

You initialize it in the constructor member initialization list:

```
class X
{
public:
    X() : CC1(25) {}  // <--- here
    const char CC1;       
    static const int SCI = 50; 
} ;
```

But if it's `25` for all instances, why not make it `static` as well? Is it in your requirements to waste memory?